# Why is the first row of my SQL query showing " to " as a data point when I CONCAT?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation, syntax-error

I am using CONCAT to combine text strings start_station_name and end_station_name (query as shown below), but when i run my query, the first row of data shows the text, "to". The rest of the query seems to run correctly. Looking for help to edit my query so this row doesn't show up.

```
SELECT 
  usertype,
  CONCAT(start_station_name," to ", end_station_name) AS route,
  COUNT(*) as num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

First row shows as follows:

```
ROW      usertype      route     num_trips     duration  
1                      to        5828994       null
```

All rows following show the correct data

Comment: Presumably you have a bunch of data in the database with null/blank values ....

Comment: `concat(null,' to ',null) = ' to '`

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT 
  usertype,
   Case when trim(start_station_name||end_station_name) is null 
Or 
trim(start_station_name||end_station_name) =''
then 
'NA'
else 
Coalesce(start_station_name,'NA')|| 'to' || coalesce (end_station_name,'NA')
End 
   AS route,
  COUNT(*) as num_trips,
  ROUND(AVG(cast(tripduration as int64)/60),2) AS duration
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips`
GROUP BY
  start_station_name, end_station_name, usertype
ORDER BY
  num_trips DESC 
LIMIT 10
```